# Microsoft Access Stop query after N results

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, limit

I have an MS Access 2007 database that needs to run from a network drive. (Any server we have access to is much slower.) The network latency still adds a lot of search time, due to the sheer quantity of data in each query.

(Yes, the database is indexed on any joined or processed fields. The application accesses it via ADODB disconnected recordsets exclusively. The search algorithm makes exactly two round-trips to the database because performance was worse with just one.)

In order to improve performance, I would like to limit the search to 30 successful results. (Probably 10 would be enough for my use case.) In order to achieve this, I use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 30...
```

In testing, I realized that the more matches in excess of 30 there are in the database, the longer my query takes, meaning even with the TOP keyword, the search still processes the entire recordset before returning the top results.

I'm looking for a trick to get the query to stop and return after a satisfactory number of matches, and not bother processing anything further. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do this.  MS Access has to generate the entire list before getting the distinct.  You could try something like this:

```
select distinct top 30 t.*
from (select top 100 *
      from . . .
     ) as t;
```

You are not guaranteed that the top 100 have 30 values, so you might need 200 or 500 or something.

This might help, but other constructs may take a lot of time, such as `order by` and `group by`.  You might not be able to accomplish what you want so simply.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps an indication that I should have used something more powerful than Access, but this was a "quick and dirty" app. Incidentally, my solution does use the approach you mention, but strangely I found that it's quite a bit faster to run the inner query separately and pass the result list to the outer query as a list of keys for a "WHERE _myKey_ IN (_myList_)" predicate.